# Number of Directed Graphs with Degree Constraint

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a way to count the number of directed graphs with $n$ vertices where each vertex has degree at most 5? (degree includes both in-degree and out-degree)

Comment: labeled or unlabeled?

Comment: @joriki labeled